# My Jar file seems to ignore my application.properties

Tags: java, jar

When I run the project on my computer, it works fine. But, when I created a jar and try to run it, the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml does not exist
```

Then, just to test, I created this file, and then it started to complain that there is no driver for the database, as if I hadn't configured it on `application.properties`.

What can cause this? because, when I just run it on the terminal, everything goes fine...

here is my application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
server.port=8080

# Spring DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=${DB_HOST:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME:admin}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD:admin}

# Liquibase
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
```